# Press both mouse buttons when holding left click

Tags: autohotkey

When I hold down left mouse button I would like for the right mouse button be held down also.

The right mouse would then release when the left mouse is no longer being held. So both buttons can be controlled simultaneously with the left click.

Answer (score 1):

`LButton::RButton` means Left Button acts like your Right Button. The `~` modifier means "Fire the hotkey as well as whatever it's remapped to".

```
~LButton::RButton
```

Quick edit: If you need it to activate after Left Button has been held for a certain amount of time, use this:

```
; Time for LButton to be held down before RButton is sent (in milliseconds)
waitTime    := 500
return

~*LButton::
    while GetKeyState("LButton", "P")
        if (A_TimeSinceThisHotkey > waitTime){
            Send, {RButton Down}
            KeyWait, LButton
            Send, {RButton Up}
        }
return
```